# Android Force Take Picture

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to force the necessity of taken at least one picture when one button is pressed. In other words, if the guy check that something is wrong, he needs to take at least one picture and maximum 3 to prove it.

So, I'm trying to find a way to check if the picture was taken or not to let the user continue to check other issue.

I will post a picture to illustrate.

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: How I can force the guy to take a picture each time he marked an issue?

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#camera-preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How I can force the guy to take a picture each time he marked an issue?

That is not strictly possible. The user can do whatever the user wants with their device, such as turn it off. Since most Android devices do not have built in guns — let alone ones that you as an app developer can control — you do not really have any way to force the user to do anything.

What you *can* do is not save the issue until you have the desired number of pictures. This is not significantly different than any other sort of form validation (e.g., confirm that the credit card number that was entered meets the Luhn checksum algorithm, confirm that the user actually entered a postal code). Only when you have all of your data do you actually save the data.

If you do not want the user to lose the data, you are welcome to save it separately (e.g., different file, in the database but with a flag indicating that it is not yet ready, in the database but in a separate table). If the user later returns to your app, you can see that the user had a partially-completed issue, then prompt them to see if they wish to finish it or abandon it. This is reminiscent of how programs like Microsoft Word handle crashes. Your document is being saved frequently to disk, in case of a crash or power loss or something, but it is not being saved to the original document file. Instead, it is saved to a temporary file, one that Word will detect when you next start it up.

<sub>Note: I have not used Microsoft Word in a very long time, so it is possible that they no longer implement this feature.</sub>

Comment: Ok, I got you. However, now I'm lost on how to make this type of validation! I will try to find something related with it.